# Running one MySQL query based on 2 conditions

Tags: mysql

I have a table with various columns in it. I want to run a query on this table that is defined by 2 conditions that rely on 2 parameters,

1. When `column_a` has a value that `is non zero`, then set the where condition to be `column_a = param_1`
2. When `column_a` has a value that `is zero`, then set the where condition to be `column_b = param_2`

My first attempt at this was the following:

```
Select * from mytable where column_a = param_1 or column_b = param_2
```

There is a relation between `column_a` and `column_b` in that when `column_a` is non zero then it will not require the latter part of the query (`or column_b = param_2`) but when `column_a` is zero then I only want to run the latter part of the query and exclude the first part (`column_a = param_1`).

Is something like this possible?

Comment: `WHERE column_a = param_1 OR (column_a = 0 AND column_b = param_2)` (assuming `param_1` will _not_ be 0)

Comment: Is `column_a` nullable? Does `@param_1` may be NULL? What condition should be applied in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add in a test for whether or not column_a is zero.  Then check the appropriate param in each case

```
Select * from mytable 
where 
(column_a = param_1 or column_a = 0) 
and 
(column_b = param_2 or column_a <> 0)
```

If a is zero, then the first clause is always true

If a is nonzero then the second clause is always true

Answer (score 1):

If you need the query to be fast then think about two separate queries combined with UNION ALL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_a = @param_1 AND column_a <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column_b = @param_2 AND column_a = 0
```

If `@param_1` cannot be zero then the condition `AND column_a <> 0` can be removed.

Comment: I doubt they'll be a significant performance difference between the two queries as-is, but this is applicable if OP wants to start adding joins in etc.

Comment: @JeffUK My queries are SARGable. https://dbfiddle.uk/AP6TJr8K